# Slim 4: Is it possible to call a route middleware with argument passed for it?

Tags: php, slim

I would like to call a route middleware with a parameter passed from the route when added. How is it possible?

```
$app->get('/path', function($request, $response, $lvlreq = 1) {
    $oViewParams = new \lib\ViewParams("referencia", "", "", "", "");
    $params = array('viewp' => $oViewParams->getMassParams());
    return $this->get('view')->render($response, 'some.html', $params);
})->add($authenticate)
  ->add($tmhasaccess);
```

First middleware doesn't need params, thats going well.

```
$authenticate = function (Request $request, RequestHandler $handler) { 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['param'])) {
        $routeContext = RouteContext::fromRequest($request);
        $route = $routeContext->getRoute();
        $redirect = $route->getPattern();
        $_SESSION['urlRedirect'] = $redirect;
        $this->get('flash')->addMessage('error', 'error');
        $response = $handler->handle($request);
        return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', '/login');
    } else {
        $response = $handler->handle($request);
        return $response;
    }
    
};
```

```
$tmhasaccess = function (Request $request, RequestHandler $handler) {
    ###I need $lvlreq value inside here to work with it. This won't work:
    $routeContext = RouteContext::fromRequest($request);
    $route = $routeContext->getRoute();
    $lvlreq = $route->getArgument('lvlreq');
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Middleware changed to class:

```
class TMHasAccessMiddleware
{
    protected $lvlreq;
    private $container;
    
    function __construct($container, $lvlreq = 0) {
        $this->lvlreq = $lvlreq;
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    
    public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response
    {
        ##$this->lvlreq now accessible.
    }
}
```

Can be called from route:

```
->add(new TMHasAccessMiddleware($container, 1));
```